# Phrase type help needed

Tags: phrases, prepositions

In the following sentence:

> I thank you for arranging the wedding.

What type of phrase is *for arranging the wedding*?

*For* is a preposition, but the fact there is not only a noun following it but also "arranging" is confusing me a little.

Then, if we swap the order of the sentence around to

> For arranging the wedding, I thank you.

What is *for* functioning as in this case?

Comment: The part after "for" is a gerund phrase, which functions as a noun. "I thank you for [NOUN]."

Comment: @Josh If you have created two accounts and would like them merged, please follow the [advice in the Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

In both sentences, "for arranging the wedding" is a prepositional phrase and "for" is the preposition. Robusto is right; "arranging the wedding" acts as a noun phrase. It's odd, because it includes a direct object ("the wedding"), but the principle is the same one that allows you to say "Thank you for clapping," in which "clapping" is more obviously noun-like because it doesn't take an object.